# how to add selected values from two <select> tag and show sum in third <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   var presentyear = new Date().getFullYear();
   for(y = 1995; y <= presentyear; y++)
   {
          var optn = document.createElement("option");
          optn.text = y;
          optn.value = y;        
        
          document.getElementById('year10').options.add(optn);
      }
     });
```

```html
<select id="year10">
  <option>select year</option>
  //all the values will be dynamically added as called by function in js
</select>

<select id="gap">
  <option value="0">Select Number of Years</option>
  <option value="1">1 year</option>
  <option value="2">2 years</option>
  <option value="3">3 years</option>
  <option value="4">4 years</option>
  <option value="5">5 years</option>
</select>

<select id="year12">
  <option id="calvalue"> </option>
</select>
```

I want to save selected values from two select tags and show the sum in a separate third select dropdown.

As in the snippet above, I have three select tags, the javascript code fills the options for 'year10' select from 1995 to 2017.
The 'gap' select have 5 values.

Now, i want to add the selected values of 'year10' and 'gap' and show in the single option (with id='calvalue') in 'year12' select tag.
Also, when i change the values in either first two selects, the summed value in year12 must change with it.

How to do this?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: Start by showing us what you have tried so far yourself

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yeah.. hold on i'm editing it

Comment: You're trying to put the result in a select - that's very odd. Would a text input not make more sense? You can make it readonly if need be

Comment: yeah sure..can you solve it using atext input with same id instead of select?

Comment: Sure, I added an answer for you.

Comment: where's your answer @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Right below this comment section :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46281132/519413

Comment: It should work for value="0"(in 'gap') as well . @RoryMcCrossan  . Kindly improve the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to cover that, although I'd suggest adding `0 years` as it's own separate option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you just need to add a `change` event handler to both of the selects which reads the values and adds them together.

Note that putting the result in another `option` of a select is a little odd. I'd suggest using a readonly text box instead, something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var presentyear = new Date().getFullYear(), options = '';
  for (y = 1995; y <= presentyear; y++) {
    options += '<option value="' + y + '">' + y + '</option>';
  }
  $('#year10').append(options);
  
  $('#year10, #gap').change(function() {
    var year = parseInt($('#year10').val(), 10) || 0;
    var gap = parseInt($('#gap').val(), 10) || 0;
    $('#year12').val(!year ? '' : year + gap);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="year10">
  <option>select year</option>
</select>

<select id="gap">
  <option value="0">Select Number of Years</option>
  <option value="1">1 year</option>
  <option value="2">2 years</option>
  <option value="3">3 years</option>
  <option value="4">4 years</option>
  <option value="5">5 years</option>
</select>

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="year12">
```

Comment: Hey, can you help on one more problem?  I got two radio buttons indicating gap and no_gap.. I want to add '0' to the 'gap' id value when i check 'no_gap'. Can you solve it?

Comment: I'll take a look. If it's too broad I'd suggest asking a new question

Comment: No its not that broad. Say if you don't understand the problem?

Comment: I replied before you edited the comment to add the detail. For that I'd suggest starting a new question as it's extra functionality over what you originally asked

Answer (score 0):

```js
function jsFunction(){
  var myselect = document.getElementById("selectOpt");
  $("#secondselectbox").val(myselect);
}
```

```html
<select onChange="jsFunction()" id="selectOpt">
    <option value="1" onclick="jsFunction()">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="secondselectbox">
</select>
```

In this code After value selection you can do any new function(another select tag).

Comment: Aside from being bad practice this doesn't even come close to answering the question

Answer (score 0):

if you're ok with jquery... then

```
<select id="num1" onchange="addThem()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select> 
<select id="num2"  onchange="addThem()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="res">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<script>
  function addThem(){
    var num1 = $("#num1").val();
    var num2 = $("#num2").val();
    $("#res").val(Number(num1) +Number(num2));
  }
</script>
```

this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kiWWt6hHLEM0h0U6xd6W?p=preview) sample i did should help you out

Answer (score 0):

You will have to work on the specifics your self, but this should get you started.

```js
let nextOption = {first: 1, seccond: 1}
function selected(selector, option) {
  if (selector === 'first') {
    nextOption.first = parseInt(option.value);
  }
  else if (selector === 'seccond') {
    nextOption.seccond = parseInt(option.value);
  }
  let newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.text = nextOption.first + nextOption.seccond;
  document.getElementById('final').add(newOption);
}
selected();
```

```html
<select onClick="selected('first', this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select onClick="selected('seccond', this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="final">
</select>
```